# Swift "Start Game Menu"

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm still very new, however I'm almost done with a game, the problem is i don't have a scene that allows the user to hit "Tap to play" so when the app loads up, the user is just thrown into into the game with no warning. I know i need to create the scene under

```
         override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
```

but i can't seem to find on how to do this! I've looked everywhere, but can't find anything to fix this, all help is appreciated, I hope this question is clear, if not, my apologies!

Comment: I would **highly** recommend [DemoBots Apple's sample code](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5-OOgku3LAhVHmHIKHXRVCRIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fsamplecode%2FDemoBots%2FIntroduction%2FIntro.html&usg=AFQjCNGCCFOQuVfuYX2rh_byV2qtxuCxiQ&sig2=UcsqrzF64H1L_tOU_joW_g). It has a lot of good architecture decisions in it with several re-useable components.

Answer (score 3):

A simple startScene with transition to a gameScene for your game could be something like this:

In your StartScene class create a constant for a `SKLabelNode`

```
// you can use another font for the label if you want...
let tapStartLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "STHeitiTC-Medium")
```

then in `didMoveToView` :

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // set the background
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    // set size, color, position and text of the tapStartLabel
    tapStartLabel.fontSize = 16
    tapStartLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    tapStartLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
    tapStartLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Center
    tapStartLabel.position = CGPoint(
        x: size.width / 2,
        y: size.height / 2
    )
    tapStartLabel.text = "Tap to start the game"

    // add the label to the scene   
    addChild(tapStartLabel)
}
```

then in `touchesBegan` to go from startScene to your current gameScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let gameScene = GameScene(size: size)
    gameScene.scaleMode = scaleMode

    // use a transition to the gameScene
    let reveal = SKTransition.doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(1)

    // transition from current scene to the new scene
    view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
}
```

to make the `StartScene` your first scene with the Tap to play label add this code in the `viewDidLoad()` method of your `GameViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = StartScene(size: view.bounds.size)

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)

}
```

It should look like that:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! code works, now i just need help with the StartScene. I created a new swift file "StartScene.swift" except i put the code you gave me in the GameScene.swift file. How do i make the "Tap to play" my first scene that comes up? Again thank you!!

Comment: Welcome, I added an initial setup for `GameViewController` to my answer, to make the `StartScene` with the "Tap to play" label your first scene

Comment: Okay now I'm getting, use of unresolved indentifer 'StartScene' error.

Comment: Did you name your class declaration `class StartScene: SKScene {...` in StartScene.swift like you create it in the GameViewController? If there is a typo error you will get the error of an unresolved identifier

Comment: WOW I see, thank you! Everything is where i need it to be, however it's not showing the "Tap To Play" scene, I'm just seeing a grey screen now when it loads up.

Comment: ok my fault. change the `fontSize` in didMoveToView of the StartScene to 16 instead of 200. I updated my answer also.

Comment: so i changed the fontSize, and the code is working, however, in the StartScene.swift file it will not load my GameScene. It's just a blank grey scene still, now if i put the code in my GameScene, the game pops up, but when you tap the screen it just triggers the menu scene over and over..

Comment: ok, I recommend you to make a new game project and create the StartScene and add the code to the Startscene, GameScene and GameViewController from my answer. I've tested it with a new clean project and it worked. After you created the new project check against your current project. There must be a typo or some similar issue